# Customised annotation in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have seen few examples where customized annotations were used. example

```
@SimpleAnnotation
class SampleBean {
  @SimpleAnnotation
  public String getName() {
    return "AAA";
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
  }

  public int getHeight() {
    return 201;
  }
}

@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface SimpleAnnotation {
}
```

Can anyone tell why we use this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Spring supports for many Annotation the concept of "meta-annotation". (I am not sure if it is for all.)

This mean that you can build your own annotation and annotate the annotation with one of springs "core" annotations.

For example:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Service
public @interface MyService {

}
```

Then you can use this annotation instead of `@Service`.  (Btw: `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` use the same technique to "inherit" from `@Component`)

---

One example that make heavy use of this is "inherit" from `@Qualifier`.
For an example and some explanation have a look at [Spring Reference Chapter: 3.9.3 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) (The Example with `@Genre` is at the end of the chapter.)

One very usefull construct that can be done with that technique is, that it enables you to combine several Annotations to a (in your use case) more meaning full. So instead of writing at every class of some type allways the same two annotations, for example: `@Service` and `@Qualifiyer("someting")`  (the org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier). You can create your custom annotation that is annotated with this two annotations, and then use in your beans only this one custom annotation. (@See [Avoid Spring Annotation Code Smell  Use Spring 3 Custom Annotations](http://java.dzone.com/articles/avoid-spring-annotation-code-smell-use-spring3-custom-annotations))

If you want to see how powerfull this technique can be use, you can have a look at Context and Dependency Injection Framework.

---

Question from the comment:

> The @interface also has some variables defined inside it, what does that signify?

The Annotations (defined by @Interface) work a bit like beans. This Fields are the properties that can/must be define if you use the annotations. The values can be later on be read via reflection API.

For example the `@Controller` Annotation in Spring:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Controller {
   String value() default "";
}
```

The field with name `value` is that field that can be used without explicit name it: (`@Controller("myUrl")` is the same `@Controller(value="myUrl")`)

Comment: Ralph: The @interface also has some variables defined inside it, what does that signify?

Comment: @Junaidaj: see my extended answer

Answer (score 8):

You can create your own meta-annotations that collect several other Spring annotations to reduce meta-boilerplate in your code:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype")
@Transactional(readOnly = true, rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
public @interface ReadOnlyService {}
```

And then you can simply write:

```
@ReadOnlyService
public class RoleService {

}
```

Spring will find the `@ReadOnlyService` and semantically replace it with:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype")
@Transactional(readOnly = true, rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
public class RoleService {

}
```

Of course having custom annotations pays of when you have tons of services annotated with the same set of Spring annotations that can be replaced with one, well named annotation.

Examples taken from: [Avoid Spring Annotation Code Smell: Use Spring 3 Custom Annotations](http://java.dzone.com/articles/avoid-spring-annotation-code-smell-use-spring3-custom-annotations)

Comment: Tomasz: I have seen some example which aslo uses

    @ReadOnlyService
    public class RoleService {
       string var;
    }
what dose that mean in the context of the example explained by you?

Comment: This means that instead of using these three annotations over and over you can replace them with one. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

Custom annotations do not do anything on their own.  They are simple markers in code.  Their real power comes from tools that look for specific annotations.  Like some of the other answers mention, Spring has several uses for annotations and now mechanisms for defining your own component types.  Pretty neat.  Another example, a few weeks ago I used AOP and a few custom annotations to provide simple method level result caching.  Now that I have the caching engine in place, and the appropriate AOP hooks defined, if I want to cache a method, I simply add that annotation. Some people simply use the annotations as fancy metadata to improve readability.

At the end of the day, they are a fairly simple tool that you can use for a great number of things.

Answer (score 0):

The best part of using custom annotations is that you don't have to make any configuration, Spring will auto detect that these beans are service components and everything will work fine. Custom Annotations are a very small feature added in Spring but are very useful.For details take a look at this

http://java.dzone.com/articles/avoid-spring-annotation-code-smell-use-spring3-custom-annotations

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- you need the `@Component` annotation on your custom annotation. That way you can use your custom annotation to mark classes as beans. In addition, you can add a default scope and other meta-information
- qualifiers - you can use qualifier annotations (annotated with the `@Qualifier` meta-annotation) to distinguish between implementations of the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is also to use annotations in AOP pointcuts. Not specifically Spring, but often employed when making use of Spring AOP.